# C# SQL Grouping Intervals using DateDiff?

Tags: c#, sql, grouping, intervals, datediff

I have the following table:

```
RowA     RowB    date_time            RowD  
-------  ------- -------------------  -------
ValueA1  ValueB1 01.01.2001 16:23:01  ValueD1  
ValueA2  ValueB2 01.01.2001 16:23:06  ValueD2  
ValueA3  ValueB3 01.01.2001 16:23:11  ValueD3  
ValueA4  ValueB4 03.01.2001 12:23:01  ValueD4  
ValueA5  ValueB5 03.01.2001 16:23:06  ValueD5  
ValueA6  ValueB6 03.01.2001 16:23:11  ValueD6  
ValueA7  ValueB7 03.01.2001 16:23:16  ValueD7
```

The table goes on like that for about 50k lines. I would like to group those values taken in 5s interval as attempt1, attempt 2... etc. I'll also need to make the groups attempt1, attempt2... etc. accessible, so I can turn on or off their visibility in a DataGridview using Checkboxes for example.

I am very new to SQL and I'm looking for a solution for two days now, tried `GROUP BY`, `DATEDIFF` and `DATEADD`, but most of the solutions I found did only count or sum up the values of the groups.

A solution using RowFilter would be awesome but the sql string would be very much appreciated, too.

**EDIT**

I am sorry I couldn't answer earlier. Both results you offered are not what I was looking for and I am not sure whether the results I wish for can be solved using SQL now. The resulting table I wish for should look like this (I added some Values because I realized that the ones I used until now probably didn't make clear what I wished for):

```
Attempt  RowA    RowB    date_time           RowD  
-------- ------- ------- ------------------- -------
attempt1 ValueA1 ValueB1 01.01.2001 16:23:01 ValueD1   |
attempt1 ValueA2 ValueB2 01.01.2001 16:23:06 ValueD2   | attempt1 since 5s difference (over 3 lines)
attempt1 ValueA3 ValueB3 01.01.2001 16:23:11 ValueD3   |
attempt2 ValueA4 ValueB4 03.01.2001 12:23:01 ValueD4  -> new and one line only attempt (difference bigger than 5s)
attempt3 ValueA5 ValueB5 03.01.2001 16:23:06 ValueD5   |
attempt3 ValueA6 ValueB6 03.01.2001 16:23:11 ValueD6   | attempt3 since 5s difference (over 3 lines)
attempt3 ValueA7 ValueB7 03.01.2001 16:23:16 ValueD7   |
attempt4 ValueA8 ValueB8 04.01.2001 02:16:53 ValueD8   - attempt4 since 5s difference...
attempt4 ValueA9 ValueB9 04.01.2001 02:16:58 ValueD9   - (2 lines)
```

Comment: From your question it is not clear what's *the criterion* for grouping the data. Is it a date? How can I be sure what is *one attempt*? A certain period has to elapse to "make it a different attempt"?

Comment: Sorry, I am having trouble to describe this problem, I know. All those values under date_time which have an interval of 5s to eachother. In this case attempt1 would be: ValuesA1,B1,D1 - ValuesA3,B3,D3 and attempt2: ValueA5,B5,D5 - ValueA7,B7,D7.

Comment: Just another question: does this table have a primary key? Can I assume that all date_time fields are unique?

Comment: Yes, all date_time fields are unique.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this can be solved using only "normal" SQL (without some iterative functions like *cursors*).

If you can assure that every attemps starts at full minutes and lasts less than 60s, then this simple approach could work:

```
  select convert(smalldatetime, date_time), 
         min(RowA), min(RowB), min(RowD), 
         max(RowA), max(RowB), max(RowD)
  from   YourTableName
  group by convert(smalldatetime, date_time)
```

But this only works because smalldatetime eliminates the seconds part of your date_time field.

Also, in my example I assume that RowA, B and D contain some values which are progressive, which I think is a wrong assumption of mine.

Probably you'll have to write some subqueries here:

**Update**

This query should list all starting attempts:

```
 select t1.*
 from   <YourTableName> t1
 where not exists(
     select * 
     from   <YourTableName> t2
     where  t2.date_time >= dateadd(s, -5, t1.date_time) 
     and    t2.date_time < t1.date_time 
 )
```

The result for the data in your example:

```
RowA    RowB    date_time               RowD
------- ------- ----------------------- -------   
ValueA1 ValueB1 2001-01-01 16:23:01.000 ValueD1
ValueA4 ValueB4 2001-03-01 12:23:01.000 ValueD4
ValueA5 ValueB5 2001-03-01 16:23:06.000 ValueD5
```

I don't know if you need the last row of every attempt in your grid's rows (in the same row) too. That would make things a little more complicated.

**Update 2:**

If you're using SQL Server 2005 (or newer), you could use Common Table Expressions like this query which gives you start and end row in single rows:

```
 with start_rows as (
     select start.* 
     from   <YourTablenName> start
     where  not exists(
       select * 
       from   <YourTableName> start2
       where  start2.date_time >= dateadd(s, -5, start.date_time) 
       and    start2.date_time < start.date_time 
     )
 ),
 stop_rows as (   
     select stop.*
     from   <YourTablenName> stop
     where  not exists(
        select * 
        from <YourTableName> stop2
        where stop2.date_time <= dateadd(s, 5, stop.date_time) 
        and   stop2.date_time > stop.date_time 
     )
 ) 
 select start_rows.*, stop_rows.*
 from   start_rows, stop_rows
 where start_rows.date_time <= stop_rows.date_time
 and    not exists(
    select * from stop_rows sr2
    where sr2.date_time < stop_rows.date_time
    and sr2.date_time >= start_rows.date_time
 )
 order by start_rows.date_time
```

The result in this case is:

```
ValueA1 ValueB1 2001-01-01 16:23:01.000 ValueD1 ValueA3 ValueB3 2001-01-01 16:23:11.000 ValueD3
ValueA4 ValueB4 2001-03-01 12:23:01.000 ValueD4 ValueA4 ValueB4 2001-03-01 12:23:01.000 ValueD4
ValueA5 ValueB5 2001-03-01 16:23:06.000 ValueD5 ValueA7 ValueB7 2001-03-01 16:23:16.000 ValueD7
```

Comment: Sadly that Solution doesn't help me. Attempts can last longer than 60s, they rarely start at full minutes and the values are not progressive. Could you please show me an example containing Subqueries?

Comment: @Na Smieci Now I understand. That's pretty different from what I thought you'd wanted to accomplish. :)